# OpenGrok Setup for SVN Repository in Linux Server and localhost URL should be accessible through Windows Browser

Tags: linux, svn

I have configured OpenGrok in Windows environment with Tomcat Server and was able to index the SVN Checked-out Project. The Search really worked fine :-)

Reference: http://algopadawan.blogspot.in/2012/07/installing-opengrok-on-windows.html

Now my requirement is, I need to configure the same OpenGrok in Linux Server which should directly access the SVN Repository Server and should hold the indexes in Linux environment itself and I should be able to access the **localhost URL** through the **Browser in Windows Environment**.

It will be great if someone helps me out with the procedure and possibility of doing the same.

Thanks in advance for the help guys !!!

Comment: Query: When I tried running the following command in Linux Environment ( java -jar opengrok.jar -W G:\opengrok-0.11.1\configuration.xml -c G:\ctags58\ctags.exe -P -S -v -s G:\CodeSource -d G:\opengrok-0.11.1\grokdata ) I am getting the following error: SEVERE: Error: No Exuberant Ctags found in PATH! (tried running /home/app/OpenGrok/Ctags/ctags.exe). For all the Generic paths I gave the exact location of the components. Please help as early as possible.

Comment: Hi All, I am eagerly waiting for the answer, please help guys !!!

Comment: I have made OpenGrok work in Linux Environment with static source (Projects made available in source path). Now I am in need of help to set remote svn repositories (with history) as source. Suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649730/how-can-you-connect-opengrok-to-a-svn-repository) out from stackoverflow.

You would need to enable the *remoteScmSupported* property in the opengrok configuration as suggested in the comments.